# How to setup near node without validating blocks?

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I want to setup a near mainnet node.
I don't want be part of validation process, I just to want to maintain a copy of mainnet.
This copy should have complete history of all the blocks and transactions.

Being validator it will require more resources.

How to setup a mainnet near node which only sync to mainnet without participating in the validation process?

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not validate blocks, how do you know any block incoming from P2P network is something you can process? Anyone could spin up a mock Near P2P node and start flooding you with crap blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run an indexing node that tracks one or more shards and gives you access to the stream of transactions. You can save them to your own database for querying, for example

https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-indexer

You can also run an archival node, similar to above but you're just tracking and storing without transforming the data in any way

https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/integrator/exchange-integration#running-an-archival-node

Comment: Thank you sherif, I will look into this.

Comment: Given your requirements, you don't need indexer, you only need a regular nearcore node configured to be archival (see the second link from Sherif)